# d3js multigraph auto update

Tags: javascript, d3.js, auto-update

I could really use some help fixing a d3js related problem.. I did everything I know and googled everywhere but still can’t figure out the solution. I’ve got a simple database as shown below. 
when executing the code it reads all the data and everything is fine, when it’s doing it’s refresh it’s updating the temperature graph but not the humidity... I tried many things including adding valueline2 to the update function but it still doesn't work...  Any help would be much appreciated thanks.

dtg                |   temperature    | hum 
2016-03-02 09:14:00      23             40
2016-03-02 09:10:00      22             45

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */

body { font: 14px Arial;}

path { 
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
/* Addon 5,6,7 - part 1*/
.grid .tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    stroke-opacity: 0.7;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.grid path {
      stroke-width: 0;
}


</style>
<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library -->    
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 50, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
/* var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse; */
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(6);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(8);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
     .interpolate("basis")  
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.dtg); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.temperature); });

// Define the 2nd line -- Addon 9 part 1
var valueline2 = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")   
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.dtg); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.hum); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Addon 5,6,7 - part 2
function make_x_axis() {        
    return d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(8)
}

function make_y_axis() {        
    return d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(8)
}


// Get the data
d3.json("data.php", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.dtg = parseDate(d.dtg);
    d.temperature = +d.temperature;
        d.hum = +d.hum; // Addon 9 part 3
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.dtg; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return Math.max(d.temperature, d.hum)+5; })]);
    // y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.temperature; })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", valueline(data));

    // Add the valueline2 path - Addon 9 part 2
    svg.append("path")      
    .attr("class", "line")
    .style("stroke", "red")
    .attr("d", valueline2(data));   

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

// Addon 4
    svg.append("g")              // Add the Y Axis
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

// Addon 5,6,7 - part 3
  svg.append("g")           
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(make_x_axis()
        .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
        .tickFormat("")
    )

    svg.append("g")         
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .call(make_y_axis()
        .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
        .tickFormat("")
    )

});


var inter = setInterval(function() {
            updateData();
    }, 5000); 

// ** Update data section (Called from the onclick)
function updateData() {

    // Get the data again
    d3.json("data.php", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.dtg = parseDate(d.dtg);
    d.temperature = +d.temperature;
    d.hum = +d.hum; 
    });

   // Scale the range of the data again 
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.dtg; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return Math.max(d.temperature, d.hum) + 5; })]); // Addon 9 part 4

    // Select the section we want to apply our changes to
    var svg = d3.select("body").transition();

    // Make the changes
    svg.select(".line").duration(750).attr("d", valueline(data));
    svg.select("x.axis").duration(750).call(xAxis);
    svg.select("y.axis").duration(750).call(yAxis);


    });
}

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: anything shows up in the console?

Comment: hi ooo, the proposed solution below worked!

Comment: Then you can accept this answer (green V) and vote it up ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give different names to your different lines. Right now both lines only have the same class: ".line".

```
// Add the valueline path.
svg.append("path")
.attr("class", "line")
.attr("id", "line1") //new id
.attr("d", valueline(data));

// Add the valueline2 path - Addon 9 part 2
svg.append("path")      
.attr("class", "line")
.attr("id", "line2") //new id
.style("stroke", "red")
.attr("d", valueline2(data));
```

Then in the update, you need to actually update both lines:

```
// Make the changes
svg.select("#line1").duration(750).attr("d", valueline(data)); //update line 1
svg.select("#line2").duration(750).attr("d", valueline2(data)); //update line 2
svg.select("x.axis").duration(750).call(xAxis);
svg.select("y.axis").duration(750).call(yAxis);
```

Another more "D3-friendly" approach would be to give the temperature data to your first path, the humidity data to the second one, and then call a variant of `valueline` on each path, each one with their respective data.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so so much for helping me out with this.